# Firebase realtime database's unknown pending issue occur every day

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have a mobile app service on Firebase.

Our service's concurrent connection is of almost 5,000 ~ 10,000.

I know, it does NOT matter with performance limitations.

But, we have an issue about Realtime Database's pending (1~3 minutes).

It occurs every single day at night time, even with few connections.

We started logging the main realtime database with Elasticsearch because of these pending issues.

This pending issue can be checked in detail.

If occurs db's pending, our app going to disable in 1~3 minutes suddenly (db load 3% -> 100%)

and we can checked 'concurrent-connect/concurrent-disconnect' of almost concurrent users in same time.

I have attached a relevant screen capture. This issue can also be checked in GCP's Stackdriver.

We guess this issue was generated logic of Firebase assigned performance because of usage difference daytime with nighttime.

I've contacted support 3 days ago but haven't received a reply yet.

So, I wondering if anyone has the same problem or knows of this issue.

- stackdriver captured
  [image: firebase pending stackdriver]
- elk captured
  [image: firebase pending elk]

Comment: Did you end up finding out what was causing this issue? We are seeing similar spikes in pending times randomly throughout the day with no real increase in database usage.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're performing a bulk read or write operation every day at the same time. This type of operation typically comes from a batch process and is unrelated to the number of active users of your app. In fact, the bulk read/write will lock out the regular users of your app.

An example of such a batch process could be a bulk read that every night synchronizes the data in the Firebase Realtime Database with Elasticsearch, but there are *many* more options.

If there's indeed a batch process that is causing this load, you'll want to look into:

- Either splitting the process into multiple smaller steps, so that they can intersperse with the traffic from your regular clients.
- Or running the same type of process on a backup of the database. Since you'd be running against a local file, it won't interfere with the regular clients, and the backup is made by an out-of-band process (so not causing interference either).

Comment: It is not same time and irregular in every day. We just know it occur 1~2 times only night time. If your guess is true, the value of kibana graph should be different. 
DB throughput was not high at the time of issue. You can see enough in the graph. But DB load change 0.5% to 100% suddenly.